# How to set and get variables when working in cmd

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I am working in `cmd` to send HTTP GET and POST requests with `cURL`.

There are many times where I am sending requests to the same pages and typing them out every time is a huge pain.

I'm trying to figure out how to use `set=` so that I can save these URLs for each time I want to use them.

I've tried

```
C:\>set page = "http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/friends"

C:\>page
'page' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>echo %page%
%page%
```

but it won't return the page name.

How can I accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\Windows\system32>set page="http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/friends"

C:\Windows\system32>echo %page%
"http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/friends"

C:\Windows\system32>set page=http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/friends

C:\Windows\system32>echo %page%
http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/friends
```

Don't use spaces around `=`. Select version with or without `"` according to your needs. Variable value may contain spaces inside:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set page=http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/my friends

C:\Windows\system32>echo %page%
http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/my friends
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value `"http://www.mywebpage.com/api/user/friends"` inside the variable "page " (notice the space) since you have a space before the **=**.

So you can either retrieve the value by using `%page %` or by using `set page="http://..."` without a space between page and the equals sign

Comment: Wow that's crazy! I didn't realize spaces mattered !